# I want to run my Jbehave test through Command Line

Tags: jbehave

I want to run my Jbehave test through Command Line as currently I need to execute it from IDE.

Comment: If your test runner's name starts with "test" like `testrunner.java`, and your project is a maven project, then `mvn test`

Comment: I found an other solution by creating maven profile and its working fine for me but it would be great if you explain how can I create runner in JBehave.?

Comment: Search for posts with the jbehave tag and "testrunner"  I know I've posted a simple testrunner example at one time.  There is no one testrunner out there, you pretty much have to create one, but you can base it on the examples given on the JBehave web site, like I did.